# Lower bound for k-fold Sidon Sets

Tags: nt.number-theory, additive-combinatorics, sidon-sets

k-fold Sidon set is defined in http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v10i1r25/pdf (page #4, paragraph 4)
Does anyone know what the best known lower bound construction is for the size of k-fold Sidon Sets? Is there any lower bound construction at all? I searched a lot but unfortunately found nothing. Any help/reference would be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

> Cilleruelo, Javier, and Craig Timmons. "$k$-fold Sidon sets." [arXiv:1310.5374](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.5374) (2013).

Here is some lower-bound information as of about five years ago.
The conjecture is that $\sqrt{N}$ is a lower bound for each $k$, but
what is established is weaker than that:

---

[image: SidonSets]

          

<sup>Extract from page 2 of Cilleruelo and Timmons.</sup>

---